# Emotion detection through voice/speech solution for Mobile and web

Tags: ios, objective-c, machine-learning, speech-recognition

I have been searching for emotion detection through *voice/speech* solution on mobile (iOS) and web.

I found `Moodies-iOS` and `Vokaturi` solution, but they are not free.

I couldn't find any open source or paid version software available to integrate in my app and test the solution.

Could someone share if you have any info on this related.

Is there any OPEN SOURCE for iOS for Emotion analysis and detection through Voice/Speech, Please let me know.

Comment: I have found openEAR iOS stuff here, http://www.politepix.com/openears/tutorial/  will this work for finding emotion from speech?

Comment: Is there any OPEN SOURCE for iOS for Emotion analysis and detection through Voice/Speech, Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

As a former research in affective computing, I highly doubt you can find a ready-for-use iOS open source solution for emotion recognition from speech. The main reason is that it is a damn difficult task that requires a lot of research and a lot of proper data to train models. That is why companies like BeyondVerbal and Vokaturi do not share their models with others. Thus, you will be very lucky if you can find anything in open source, I am not even talking about iOS solutions.

I am aware about some toolkits you can use for this task (namely, the openEAR toolkit), but to build something working from it, you need an expert knowledge in the field and data to train models. A comprehensive list of databases can be found here: http://emotion-research.net/wiki/Databases. A lot of them a freely available.

Answer (score 1):

As Dmytro Prylipko said it is very doubtful that there is any open-source lib for emotion recognition from speech.

You may write your own solution. It is not hard. Trouble is, as mentioned before, proper training and/or trasholding takes a lot of time and nerves.

I will give you a short theory how you should begin writing the algo, but training and so on is on you.

First big trouble is that different people differently relay their emotions vocally.
For example: one shocked person will to their shock respond with overexclaimed sentence while another will "freeze" and their response would sound very flat (almost robot-like).
Therefore you will need a lot of templates from which to learn how to classify your input speech by emotions.

You can remove some difficulties by using context recognition along with voice prosody.
That is what I'd advise you to do.

First make an algorithm that will use speech-recognized text to put it into emotion context. E.g. you can use specific words and phrases that people use when expressing different emotions.

That is easily done. You may use a neural network or simple branching or whatever.

So you will be able to recognize whether person is thankful and surprised at the same time by combining context recognition and emotions from prosody.

Now, to recognize the emotion from prosody you have to get prosody parameters and some others.

For example, some emotions may be recognized by looking at duration of particular words in a sentence.

So you have the sentence and the text of that sentence. You know that the speed of normal speech is approximately 200 words per minute. Knowing this and number of words in the sentence you can see how fast is someone talking. Then you measure the duration of each word and get its speed. By knowing how fast is the speech and how long is the word you can get normalized ratios that can be used for classifications in order to determine the closest guess of the emotion.

For instance, when someone is presented with a present that he/she likes very much, the "thank you" will sound pretty long. It will also be of higher pitch than that person's usual speech.

So the next step would be to get the average pitch for each word to see the relation between them. So you will be able to see how the sentence prosody modulates. From lower to higher, or vice versa.

Also, how prosody changes inside the phrases within the sentence.

You may go about this by comparing curves of known emotion directly, or you may use aproximation to get coefficients from the prosody curve vector. The square function does good for normal speech prosody (with no particular emotions in). So some higher order polynomial should do. So, you can get coefficients of the polynom and use them to get what emotion should whole sentence or phrase relay.

The same goes for individual words within the sentence. You get the pitch for each phoneme or syllable or just the pitch curve for e.g. every 20 ms of the word. Then you either calculate few coefficients to aproximate the polynom you decided is good enough for you, or you take the whole curve and normalize it to e.g. 30 points to use it with recognition.

To compare curves directly you may use gesture recognition algorithm by Oleg Dopertchouk:

http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article2039.asp

I tried it on pitch curves of melodies, it works just fine.

The trouble is, you need a database of speech with context and emotion with clear manually done classification to give your algo something to compare with.

If you use polynomials instead of whole curves, you can do some recognition by using thresholds on coefficients, but results will be a bit shaky. Only real excuse for using coeffs at all is that you do not need to know how long is the word in question. I.e. the same polynom should work on a word with 2 phonemes and on one with 5. (should work)

You see, a theory is nice and easy. Use speech recognition, measure speech rate, and duration of each word, construct pitch curve for whole phrase and pitch curve for each word using FFT, do some comparison between ready database and the input. And walla, emotion recognized.

But where will you find the database with word curves marked with emotions.
For example, you would need for each emotion at least one pitch curve for words with different number of phonemes. At least one, because it is important whether the word starts with vowel or ends with one, or simply someone differently relays the same emotion even if the curve represents the same word.

OK, so you can say that you can make one. Where would you find recorded samples to make your curves or calculate coeffs? Hm, perhaps a recording of some drama. Not bad idea, but the acted emotions aren't the same as the natural ones.

It is a big job to teach a machine such a thing.

Oh, yeah, I almost forgot, emotions aren't only, or sometimes at all transfered using pitch changes, sometimes it's only the way in which the word is being pronounced.

So, for some cases, you would probably need LPC or some other coefficients showing some more info on how phonemes in the word sounds. Or you would need to take in view other harmonics from FFT, not just the one representing the pitch of excitation train.

The best that you can do without following my hints and developing your own algo, is to use NLTK (natural language toolkit) to develop a statistical speech (emotionally rich) model and use algorithms from there (perhaps a bit modified) to try to get to the emotion in question.

But I fear it would be a greater job than going from zero. As far as I know NLTK doesn't support emotions. Just normal speech prosody.

You may try to integrate some things I wrote about into Sphinx, to develop emotion based speech models and introduce emotion recognition directly into sphinxes VR algorithm.

If you really need this, I advise you to learn enough DSP to write your own algo, then pay someone to make you initial database from audiobooks, radio dramas and similar stuff (using a tool you provide).

After your algo starts to work reasonably well, implement autolearning by giving users an option to correct the algo's wrong guesses. After some time you will get 90% reliable algo to recognize emotions from speech.